# Deleting bigquery automatic backups/snapshots

Tags: security, google-bigquery, database-backups, time-travel

If sensitive data was to enter a bigquery table, is it possible to permanently delete the automatic backups that are used by the time travel feature before the retention period (default of 7 days, but can be a minimum of 2 days) elapses?

Thus making it impossible to roll back and recover a snapshot of the table that contains the sensitive data and allowing for a complete and irreversible purge of the data from the project.

I haven't yet seen anything in the BQ google docs to suggest this is possible or how to handle a situation like this, but this seems like a big caveat to handling sensitive data in bigquery.

If this is not possible what other options are there to restrict access to the historical data in bigquery? Is time travel a permission that can be withdrawn by a custom role?